# Azure role being queried (GET /) every 5 minutes from Microsoft IP address

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

In one of our Azure roles we have a log that is accumulating a lot of HTTP 404 errors as a result of regular HTTP requests (Get / ) coming from an IP address belonging to MS.

Is this "traffic" part of the Azure role health monitoring?  We don't have a controller/action to respond to that request.  I would prefer not to open that door unnecessarily, but if I could unambiguously identify it as Azure health monitoring, then I could at least filter them out when logging.

Comment: If you've set up endpoint monitoring for your cloud service, maybe that's it?

Comment: I see it's an old issue, but did you manage to find any real cause why it was happening? It happens for all my websites in 4 different subscriptions. The problem for us it's not the requests themselves, but that they are pinging the wrong URL (it pings default *.azurewebsites.net on HTTP, while it should be our dedicated domain and HTTPS).

Comment: "Always On" is ON under the Configuration / General settings of your AppService. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75141212/968003

Answer (score 9):

The 5 minutely requests to `HTTP GET /` are caused by the "AlwaysOn" feature of Azure Web Apps.

Since it is not possible to customize the endpoint AlwaysOn checks, your options are;

1. Disable AlwaysOn
2. Live with the errors in your logs
3. Add a controller/ action that handles the default route