# Why I got an error request every 5 minutes in an Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a java web app on Azure, and I got failed requests in it's Application Insights. It look likes someone are calling 'http://myApp.azurewebsites.net/error' every 5 minutes, but I do not have this interface, so there are many failed requests with 404 in Application Insights. Then I add this interface in app, but there are still many failed requests with 404 code. I have no idea about those requests, I do not know where are them from or what do them want to do. Did I set wrong configurations in my app?

Comment: there is alot of botnets and other bad actors out there testing IPs and such for vulnerabilities. Its likely that someone is trying to "hack" your app. Probably not target specifically towards you but on a whole ip range for example.  For this kind of stuff there are web application firewalls (WAF) https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Firewall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting named 'Always on' in App Service's configuration, and it's works fine when I turned off this setting.

Answer (score 13):

It's caused by "**Always On**" being **ON** under the `Configuration / General` settings of your AppService.

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common?tabs=portal#configure-general-settings):

> **Always On**: Keeps the app loaded even when there's no traffic. When **Always On** is not turned on (default), the app is *unloaded after 20 minutes* without any incoming requests. The unloaded app can cause high latency for new requests because of its warm-up time. When **Always On** is turned on, **the front-end load balancer sends a GET request to the application root every five minutes**. The continuous ping prevents the app from being unloaded.

If you need to keep the "**Always On**", then to mitigate the impact, you can do one of these:

- add a controller/action that handles the default route;
- (a more fragile option) add a redirect policy to an existing route based on `^AlwaysOn$` pattern in the `User-Agent` header (here's the [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/404-response-code-caused-by-app-services-alwayson-feature/), as suggested by @AussieJoe in the comments).

Comment: Something like this works in an aspnetcore app: 
`app.MapGet("/", () => { return "Always On"; });`

Comment: I disagree with Alex's answer. I'm investigating the exact same thing, a "heartbeat" of 404 GET requests to our Azure Web App and we DO NOT have Always On enabled.

Comment: @LilGames, there're can be other reasons too. Like a WAF/FrontDoor in front of the service pinging it.

Comment: You can also override the "action" url in the server rules. I think this is a better answer than adding extra erroneous endpoints that do very little. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/404-response-code-caused-by-app-services-alwayson-feature/

Answer (score 1):

To narrow down this issues, you can enable the Diagnostic log for your web apps. Web Server Diagnostic logging helps you to trace the exception details originate from components. And if you suspect error comes from your application then "Application Diagnostic" is the source to trace the reason for errors.

Also, Enable the log stream on your web app so irrespective of peak or off peak hours, you can monitor the live log stream , how your web app performs and respond to each request.

Comment: There is a setting named 'Always on' in App Service's configuration, and it's works fine when I turned off this setting, thank you very much~

Answer (score 0):

The valid answer is the one from @Alex Klaus. I experienced the same behaviour, Azure calls the web app once every 5 minutes when "**Always On**" is enabled.

Do not disable it if you want your app to stay alive and avoid cold start ups.

Just implement a simple "/" endpoint as stated above.

Comment: or avoid erroneous endpoints that do very little but require support and security. instead, overwrite the server rules and point to a valid uri/path: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/404-response-code-caused-by-app-services-alwayson-feature/

Comment: I don't think overwriting server rules is a straightforward solution. Additionally, that solution is meant for Internet Information Services (IIS) server and best used when you want to warm up a specific endpoint from Azure App Service. I deploy on Linux machines with Kestrel. In most scenarios having a specific health-check endpoint in "/" is simpler and easier.